# I have to press enter to get the formula to run?

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a macro that does this:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COVAR(" & ticker & "!I:I," & MarketIndex & "!I:I)/VARP(" & MarketIndex & "!I:I)"
```

Which inserts this:

```
=COVAR(BMY!I:I,GSPC!I:I)/VARP(GSPC!I:I)
```

But it shows up as `#NAME?` until I click on the cell to show the formula and I press enter. Why doesn't it automatically run without intervention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to assign a `A1` style reference to a `R1C1` style property, you can't mix these types.

Either use

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=COVAR(" & ticker & "!I:I," & MarketIndex & "!I:I)/VARP(" & MarketIndex & "!I:I)"
```

Or

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COVAR(" & ticker & "!C9," & MarketIndex & "!C9)/VARP(" & MarketIndex & "!C9)"
```